# Transfer folder from localhost to server

Tags: server, macosx, scp

I'm trying to upload a folder on my server with this command:

```
sudo scp -r the_map username@ec2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

After running command on terminal on localhost. It completes, but I can't find the map/folder on my ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an often made error and I've done it myself dozens of times. And still do.

The syntax to specify a remote location for [`scp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/scp.1.html) is

```bsh
[[username@]hostname:]file
```

So if you want to affect files *remotely* then you would add a colon `:` to the hostname, as in

```bsh
scp -r the_map username@ec2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:
#                                        important colon   ^
```

When the colon is not not present, `scp` interprets 
`username@ec2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` as a (weird but valid)
filename and recursively copies the local folder `the_map` to the
local folder `username@ec2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Just remove your local folder with `rm -r 'username@ec2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com'` and run the corrected `scp` command again.